# Non-interactive bash script re logging after `usermod -aG`

Tags: linux, bash

There are commands that require users to be in a group to execute.
I am running a non-interactive bash script `script.sh` like below

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sudo usermod -aG $USER docker

# this line requires user logging to succeed
docker ps
```

When invoking the script for the first time `bash script.sh`, the line `docker ps` will complain insufficient permission since the new group membership modified by line `sudo usermod -aG $USER docker` requires the user to re-log into the shell to take effect.

My question: is there a way I can trigger the re-log in an non-interactive way?

Comment: Your script should not be adding the user to any groups (if for no other reason than adding the user to the group only needs to be done once, not every time the user tries to use `docker`.) The user being in the necessary group should be a *prerequisite* of running the script.

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes to users like adding, removing groups, you will have to logout from the current session and then, you will be able to use the docker command without any problem.
Another solution if you are working with terminal can use the `su` command.
For example, your script can be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo usermod -aG $USER docker
su - $USER #this line is used to login with the $USER as a login shell
```

The `docker ps` command will not work in this script, I forgot to mention that when you run `su - $USER` you will have to type that command inside that login shell.
But, there is another solution for that, you can use the `-c` option for `su` command. For example:

```
su - $USER -c "docker ps"
```

Or if you want to use several command you can try using a semicolon at the end of each script:

```
su - $USER -c "docker ps;docker images;..."
```

Or if you will have several commands, you can save them inside a file and send the text as parameter of the `-c` option:

**In your text file might be (dockerscripts.txt):**

```
docker ps
docker images
docker info
```

**And the `su` command might be:**

```
su - $USER -c "$(cat dockerscripts.txt)"
```

A tip for checking the current groups of a logged user is to use the command `groups`
So, if you try this:

```
sudo usermod -aG $USER docker
groups # this will display the current groups of $USER but the `docker` group will not be there yet
su - $USER
```

After that command you will be in the login shell, so you will have to type the command `groups` and when you run it, this will display the current groups of $USER including the `docker` group.

**Note:** When you logout from the login shell `su - $USER` the group will not be there again, so If you want to use the docker command you will have to use `su - $USER` again. The effective way for working with the new group is to log out from the session (if you are working with a desktop environment).

You can check this link fore more useful information: [newgrp command in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out)

Comment: When I add `su - $USER` to the non-interactive script, before `docker ps`, this will start a new shell process and the following lines like `docker ps` cannot be executed automatically.

Comment: @YuhuiShi oh yes, I forgot to mention it. I will edit the answer.